# $pdo->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES) causes exception

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working with a colleague on integrating some code. In his code, he makes a call `$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES, true);`

However this messes up my code, because I have `ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES` set to false, so we are trying to update his code to detect the current value and switch back to it after his code has run.

We tried this with `$pdo->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES);`, but it fails with the error `SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support that attribute`.

Looking at the [php page for getAttribute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.getattribute.php), I don't see `ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES` listed.

I do not understand why `setAttribute()` works for `ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES`, but `getAttribute()` does not. Is there a different way to get the currently set value for `ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES`?

PHP 7.2, MySQL 5.7.25, Ubuntu 18

Comment: [Are you sure that property for `getAttribute` exists?](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.getattribute.php#refsect1-pdo.getattribute-parameters) Also, [`setAttribute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php#refsect1-pdo.setattribute-description)

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, I don't see that property listed for `getAttribute()`. For `setAttribute()` it certainly works and changes what is returned by `->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`. The constant itself is definitely defined and has an integer value of 14. It is listed at https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php#pdo.constants.attr-fetch-table-names